# Javascript Multiplication Table Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have been trying to do this for a while and I can't quite get it. I basically want a 2d array that is a multiplication table. So if I reference multTable[5][5] I would get 25. I have found scripts for a table that is printed but not one for an array. This is the best code I have so far.

```
var multTable;
for(var v = 0; i<13; v++) {
    for(var i = 0; i<13; i++) {
        multTable[v][i]=i*v
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Also do you ever set multTable to a value? Also also in your first for loop you're using i instead of v.

Comment: You might want to start at 1 rather than 0 for a multiplication table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have built-in type of multi-dimensional array. So you can't declare multTable first and then directly use multTable[v][i]=i*v. You need to create an array of arrays.

```
var multTable = [];
for (var v = 0; v < 13; v++) {
    multTable.push([]);
    for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        multTable[v].push(i * v);
    }
}

multTable[5][5] // 25
```

Or alternatively, you can use object.

```
var multTable = {};
for (var v = 0; v < 13; v++) {
    multTable[v] = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        multTable[v][i] = i * v;
    }
}

multTable[5][5] // 25
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfect. I forgot the array within array thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what the question is, but it looks like your first for loop exit condition is using the wrong variable. Try the following:

```
var multTable;
for(var v = 0; v<13; v++) {
    for(var i = 0; i<13; i++) {
        multTable[v][i]=i*v
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I feel kinda retarded now.